# Custom Arraylist Object in Java losing element on addAll()

Tags: java, list, inheritance, arraylist, overriding

I have a custom java class extending ArrayList which overrides a number of methods to suit the functionality I need (I have a HashMap in the object I use for referencing indices). I've found that when attempting to populate the object using an array, it seems to lose an element in the process (seemingly the top element of the array).

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this is. Here is the code responsible for adding new elements to this object:

```
@Override
public boolean add(SiteEntry object) {
    if(object == null)
        return false;

    int index;
    //Removes previous entry
    if(urlMap.containsKey(object.url())){
        index = urlMap.get(object.url());
        super.remove(index);
    }

    //Adds New Entry at the bottom of the list
    super.add(object);
    urlMap.put(object.url(), indexOf(object));

    return true;
}

@Override
public void add(int index, SiteEntry object) {
    if(object == null || index < 0 || index >= size())
        return;

    //Adds entry at the specified index
    super.add(index, object);

    int size = size();
    SiteEntry temp;
    //Updates URL Map
    for(int i = index; i < size; i++){
        temp = get(i);
        urlMap.put(temp.url(), i);
    }
}

public boolean addAll(SiteEntry[] entries) {
    if(entries == null)
        return false;

    int length = entries.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        add(entries[i]);

    return true;
}
```

A SiteEntry object is the type of object the list consists of, and each one has two strings (a url, and a title). The urlMap is the Hashmap which maps urls to indices for quick referencing. I did not override the get(int index) method. I need to determine why I'm losing this element and fix the class.

Comment: Your losing the top element of the array that is being added or the top element that's already present in the list?

Comment: The top element of the array that is being added. I'm going to update the post to specify.

Comment: I miss some pieces to compile your code, please post a full working example with a main running it and pointing out your problem.

Comment: @JohnRiley It appears to be working fine when I tested. Can you provide the inputs you're passing to the addAll method? Also, does the list contain already predefined elements?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a Set instead of a List, given that the reference Map will only accept each URL once, too?

Comment: @Christian I'm using the indexing of the List to provide the ordering, as the order of the elements shift any time an entry is updated. Could I accomplish this as easily with a set?

Comment: @PascalHeraud

While isolating my code and putting it in it's own project, the bug appears to have disappeared for me. This is unusual, because the same classes in my Android project are still presenting the bug. I can't see how the platform would make the difference, as I'm not using any Android specific methods when I encounter the bug.

Comment: Repeat the mantra "Composition before Inheritance!" I would like to warn you about extending framework classes, I would recommend that you use composition instead. You could have your class implement the List interface and delegate to an Internal ArrayList. The problem with inheritance is that you need to know how if any of the super methods, invoke other methods (which you may have overridden), and even if you read and understand the source, how says the internals of a class can't change in the next JVM release.

Comment: @BandiKishore While attempting to debug my own inputs to answer your question, it looks like not only is part of my problem related to the fact that my class is designed to remove duplicates and the array being passed contained duplicates, but it seems that the contents of the array did not match the data that was being passed to them either.

Simply put: This problem goes much further than this class, and I'll need to further diagnose the problem before I can expect any outside help.

Comment: @JohnRiley Guess I was thinking of [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), but I was a bit in a daze when I first saw the question, so it's probably not what you want after all... Feel free to ignore me. ;-)